# localstack default port conflict

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04, localstack

Recently, I've started using `localstack`. However, after a day of usage, I encountered the following error while running `localstack`:

```bash
> localstack start -d                 

     __                     _______ __             __
    / /   ____  _________ _/ / ___// /_____ ______/ /__
   / /   / __ \/ ___/ __ `/ /\__ \/ __/ __ `/ ___/ //_/
  / /___/ /_/ / /__/ /_/ / /___/ / /_/ /_/ / /__/ ,<
 /_____/\____/\___/\__,_/_//____/\__/\__,_/\___/_/|_|

  LocalStack CLI 2.3.1

[22:38:49] starting LocalStack in Docker mode                localstack.py:495
           preparing environment                               bootstrap.py:1197
           configuring container                               bootstrap.py:1205
2023-10-03T22:38:49.655  WARN --- [  MainThread] l.utils.docker_utils       : Unexpected error when attempting to determine container port status: ('Docker process returned with errorcode 125', b'', b'docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint focused_hawking (971564b7717a66fa84babce1ba3988c842735ffbeb1ba88c0a6560892cf75c27): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:53: bind: address already in use.\n')
           starting container                                  bootstrap.py:1215
[22:38:51] detaching
```

Apparently, there's a conflict binding port `53` between `localstack` and `systemd-resolve`.

```bash
> sudo lsof -i :53  

[sudo] password for benyamin: 
COMMAND    PID            USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd-r 1226 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  28249      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.53:domain 
systemd-r 1226 systemd-resolve   14u  IPv4  28250      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:domain (LISTEN)
```

How can I change the default port of `localstack` to solve the issue?

---

[**VERSIONS**]:

`locakstack` version: 2.3.1
OS: Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An immediate workaround would be to [run LocalStack inside a docker container](https://docs.localstack.cloud/getting-started/api-key/#starting-localstack-via-docker). In this case all ports are isolated from the host system and you can expose them as you see fit. For more complex setups and port mappings it is probably best to use a `docker-compose.yaml`.

Port 53 is used for DNS resolving, and it seems that our internal resolver clashes with a resolver installed on your machine.

Comment: I appreciate your support. So I had to stop and uninstall the `localstack` via `localstack stop` and `pip uninstall localstack` respectively, and then install it using `docker compose`. It seems like there aren't any issues.